# How to get the max precision of a row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How do you get the max precision of a certain column (4th column) in pandas?

```
0,1609700190538,16589293,89.964,2.3,True
1,1609700191070,16589294,89.947,1.9,True
2,1609700192529,16589295,89.939,1.1,True
3,1609700192529,16589296,89.93,0.1,True
4,1609700195083,16589297,89.95,1.2,True
```

In this case precision 3.

Comment: What are you defining as precision? Number of digits after the decimal point? In which case isn't the 4th (both counting from 0 and 1) row precision 2?

Comment: Also, what is the structure of this data? Are we looking at a csv file right now? Or is it a dataframe that is missing its header?

Comment: Yeah I mean numbers of digits after the decimal points. I was counting from 1, this column has some numbers with 3 digits. This is a csv file.

Comment: `df['4th_column_name'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split('.')[-1])).max()`